# What is the difference between how these two patterns in jQuery access the DOM?

Tags: jquery, dom

These two patterns yield different results, but conceptually I would expect them to be the same. The first just updates an existing `<div>` while the second appends `<div>`s sequentially. I anticipated that both would result with this second pattern. So I am curious about the differences in how these two patterns access the DOM to give the results they do.

**Pattern 1**

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var list = [
        'My','name','is','Jonas'
        ];

    $(list).each( function (key) {
        $("body").append("<div>").text(list[key]);
                  });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vtKEq/

**Pattern 2**

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var list = [
        'My','name','is','Jonas'
        ];

    $(list).each( function (key) {
        $("<div />").text(list[key]).appendTo("body")
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MLFbw/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that

**Pattern1** Add `div` into `body` and then change `body` text.
**Pattern2** Create `div` change it's `text` and then append to `body`

**Why it happens ?**
Because the first pattern's selector is `body`, so when you use `text` it changes `body` text.

**How to fix ?**

```
$("body").append("<div>" + list[key] + "</div>");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var list = [
        'My','name','is','Jonas'
        ];

    $(list).each( function (key) {
        $("body").append($("<div>").text(list[key]));
                  });
});
```

You need to create a div and append it to body considering first scenario which behaves the same